# Minix randomly fails to accept keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, minix

I'm currently toying around with Minix 2.0.4 on a somewhat dated 80386 based system with 8 MiB of RAM. I've succesfully managed to install Minix, but I randomly encounter the following issue:

When I boot the system, the POST and boot manager accept keyboard input just fine, but once Minix has booted, no keyboard input is accepted. This bug only happens sometimes and is completely unpredictable.

What can I do?

Comment: Does it happen with other OSes? Try booting from a Linux rescue CD or live CD, for example.

Comment: It didn't happen when I installed a Xenix. I can't boot a Linux CD, mainly because it doesn't have an optical disk drive, but also because the BIOS can only boot from floppy or hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Minix 2.0.4 dates from 2005 or so, many links (even to the official places) have gone dead. It is very, very unlikely that you get to solve your problem (unless you happen to stumble upon a cabal of Minix lovers who still keep it alive).

Why are you interested in Minix 2? Doesn't Minix 3 serve?

Comment: I can't use Minix 3 or most other operating systems because the system is too old. It's an 80386-based computer with 8 MiB of RAM.